# updating 'image-path' column in database with latest updated image by user

Tags: mysql

I store path of profile picture of my users in database and images are saved with the id of user as a suffix.Now as the same user again uploads its image,I want the path to be updated.I have three columns in the image table.

1.username
2.path
3.date

I tried to use REPLACE instead of INSERT like this

$query="REPLACE INTO img_upload(username,path,created) values('".$session_user['college_id']."','".$target."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())."')";

but it didn't worked.
username is primary key.

Comment: name of the image remains same...so path would also remain same...so i guess that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really tell from your question if you want [INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or or an `UPDATE` statement. This will insert a row if the key is not a duplicate and UPDATE it otherwise.

```
INSERT INTO img_upload (username,path,created) 
VALUES ('".$session_user['college_id']."','".$target."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())."')"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE path=$target, created=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())."')
```

Or a simple update.

```
UPDATE img_upload SET path=$target, date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())."') WHERE username=$session_user['college_id']
```

Comment: yes if the user changes its profile picture...username would remain same...name of the image would also remain same...as i rename them everytime with their college ID's...so what should be done

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything I guess? If the path is the same, you don't neet to update it?